# Where are my managed threads in W3WP

Tags: c#, multithreading, count, w3wp

I create some managed threads inside an asp.net application (`System.Threading.Thread`). Each thread creates a row in a database and deletes it after the work is done (~3-5 minutes).

When I look thread count of `w3wp` in `task manager` of windows, the thread count is less than what I expect. For example if I have 100 running jobs according to database, there are 50 threads in `w3wp`. It is very fluctuating and sometimes it's one to one.

Does `thread count` in `task manager` count managed threads? If yes, then where are my threads ?

Comment: How are you creating your managed threads?

Comment: @Hero: `System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread()`

Comment: Having the number of managed threads isn't very meaningful as a metric; most of those threads will have near-zero overhead when they're sleeping. Why do you want to know?

Comment: @Hero: I know know the count, I can trace if any of them fail to remove corresponding data-row from database (kind of health monitoring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An operating-system [thread] has no fixed relationship to a managed thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between managed and unmanaged threads. Specifically, **a sophisticated host can use the Fiber API to schedule many managed threads against the same operating system thread**, or to move a managed thread among different operating system threads.

- Source: [Managed and Unmanaged Threading in Microsoft Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx)

Comment: So how can I have the real count of my managed threads inside w3wp?

Comment: There really isn't any way to do that; W3WP is an unmanaged process that executes some managed code - you can only examine it from an unmanaged perspective.